# Get data from inside a <script> tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use Beautifulsoup to get data from a website where the data I need is inside a <script> tag.

I get a response looking like this and want to get the content of "name", "thumbnailUrl, account, Id":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var modelData = {
            name: 'somename',
            thumbnailUrl: 'https://website.com/blob/bG9uZ2RhbjovL0ZPVVIvbGRwcm9kLWRlL3ljb3B6YTY4N0pnQ2Nfc3JYcVV3VXc9PQ',
            account: '5LH7J44IYPAGEZEYA9KIL',
            Id: 'someid'
        };
        store.initOmlib({"ClusterEndpoints":{"ONE":["http://us.site.me"],"TWO":["http://sg.site.me"],"FOUR":["http://de.site.me"],"FIVE":["http://in.site.me"],"SIX":["http://ja.site.me"],"SEVEN":["http://br.site.me"]},"ClusterEndpointsInternal":{"ONE":["http://usi.site.me"],"TWO":["http://sgi.site.me"],"FOUR":["http://dei.site.me"],"FIVE":["http://ini.site.me"],"SIX":["http://jai.site.me"],"SEVEN":["http://bri.site.me"]},"ClusterKeys":{"FIVE":"Cf0Mw0I2/cZf6alwfMhelEEOb6xq23IhPvC9E4eoaXU=","SIX":"bfYXVkWhs/gv+TCJ3EeeEE3oxiZRDpJO0fecUGdq2Qg=","ONE":"xkkzyNJmZ1DmNPxGwrykZ2O91f10KNXQvspa15nKKGs=","FOUR":"xMRCvh1eki9JEceBcV7Bx49uaQYpX8FdD0eZ+LCGqCc=","TWO":"XaG4I7b7wDOZ+lGHSPwbJ2HLkIFf0UGYAWz9c9LkiQk=","SEVEN":"LuSOGA/u5PL7rP8PG3cr6bqgQy7jXEv65iuHUX9ePQY="},"DefaultCluster":"ONE","IdpEndpoints":["http://idp.site.me"],"IdpKey":"MIOC9PS8KIwXOXSHtplBZLSpIqcifns0jzExtkHXw1g=","ReadOnlyEndpoints":["http://site.gg"],"ReadOnlyKey":"QKxHfdLVgbn+VYpnUiCFLMq/hhUpkpx7occEY3Z0Wnk="}, {"Id":"001026a1c1064a1b9305400814783c2385e2a978f13a","Secret":"0110de13b2187fe3078e13d9f6ad4e7567fdc143e915c9cb4df67ca"});

        if (store.renderArc) {
            store.renderArc(document.getElementById('root'), modelData, translateTable);
        } else {
            store.renderUser(document.getElementById('root'), modelData, translateTable);
        }
    </script>
```

My code to get the above response is this:

```
url = 'https://website.com'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})[6]
print(results)
```

How can I get inside the <script> tag and get the data inside?
I've looked at several other posts on here, but none which I have successfully been able to get working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example how to convert the javascript object to JSON:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<script type="text/javascript">
        var modelData = {
            name: 'somename',
            thumbnailUrl: 'https://website.com/blob/bG9uZ2RhbjovL0ZPVVIvbGRwcm9kLWRlL3ljb3B6YTY4N0pnQ2Nfc3JYcVV3VXc9PQ',
            account: '5LH7J44IYPAGEZEYA9KIL',
            Id: 'someid'
        };
        store.initOmlib({"ClusterEndpoints":{"ONE":["http://us.site.me"],"TWO":["http://sg.site.me"],"FOUR":["http://de.site.me"],"FIVE":["http://in.site.me"],"SIX":["http://ja.site.me"],"SEVEN":["http://br.site.me"]},"ClusterEndpointsInternal":{"ONE":["http://usi.site.me"],"TWO":["http://sgi.site.me"],"FOUR":["http://dei.site.me"],"FIVE":["http://ini.site.me"],"SIX":["http://jai.site.me"],"SEVEN":["http://bri.site.me"]},"ClusterKeys":{"FIVE":"Cf0Mw0I2/cZf6alwfMhelEEOb6xq23IhPvC9E4eoaXU=","SIX":"bfYXVkWhs/gv+TCJ3EeeEE3oxiZRDpJO0fecUGdq2Qg=","ONE":"xkkzyNJmZ1DmNPxGwrykZ2O91f10KNXQvspa15nKKGs=","FOUR":"xMRCvh1eki9JEceBcV7Bx49uaQYpX8FdD0eZ+LCGqCc=","TWO":"XaG4I7b7wDOZ+lGHSPwbJ2HLkIFf0UGYAWz9c9LkiQk=","SEVEN":"LuSOGA/u5PL7rP8PG3cr6bqgQy7jXEv65iuHUX9ePQY="},"DefaultCluster":"ONE","IdpEndpoints":["http://idp.site.me"],"IdpKey":"MIOC9PS8KIwXOXSHtplBZLSpIqcifns0jzExtkHXw1g=","ReadOnlyEndpoints":["http://site.gg"],"ReadOnlyKey":"QKxHfdLVgbn+VYpnUiCFLMq/hhUpkpx7occEY3Z0Wnk="}, {"Id":"001026a1c1064a1b9305400814783c2385e2a978f13a","Secret":"0110de13b2187fe3078e13d9f6ad4e7567fdc143e915c9cb4df67ca"});

        if (store.renderArc) {
            store.renderArc(document.getElementById('root'), modelData, translateTable);
        } else {
            store.renderUser(document.getElementById('root'), modelData, translateTable);
        }
    </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
# locate the script, get the contents
script_text = soup.select_one("script").contents[0]

# get javascript object inside the script
model_data = re.search(r"modelData = ({.*?});", script_text, flags=re.S)
model_data = model_data.group(1)

# "convert" the javascript object to json-valid object
model_data = re.sub(
    r"^\s*([^:\s]+):", r'"\1":', model_data.replace("'", '"'), flags=re.M
)

# json decode the object
model_data = json.loads(model_data)

# print the data
print(model_data["name"])
print(model_data["thumbnailUrl"])
print(model_data["account"])
```

Prints:

```
somename
https://website.com/blob/bG9uZ2RhbjovL0ZPVVIvbGRwcm9kLWRlL3ljb3B6YTY4N0pnQ2Nfc3JYcVV3VXc9PQ
5LH7J44IYPAGEZEYA9KIL
```

---

Or: Just parse it with `re` (`html_doc` is the same as in previous example):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
script_text = soup.select_one("script").contents[0]

name = re.search(r"name: '(.*?)'", script_text).group(1)
thumbnailUrl = re.search(r"thumbnailUrl: '(.*?)'", script_text).group(1)
account = re.search(r"account: '(.*?)'", script_text).group(1)

print(name)
print(thumbnailUrl)
print(account)
```

Prints:

```
somename
https://website.com/blob/bG9uZ2RhbjovL0ZPVVIvbGRwcm9kLWRlL3ljb3B6YTY4N0pnQ2Nfc3JYcVV3VXc9PQ
5LH7J44IYPAGEZEYA9KIL
```

Comment: I also have another one that just looks like this:

`<script>
      var modelData = {
        "hlsUrl": "null",
        "account": "4LH7J44IYPAGEZEY6E3UL"
      }
  </script>`
But I get:
 model_data = model_data.group(1) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Why doesn't it work when it's just <script> and not <script type="text/javascript"> or what is the problem since it doesn't work?